# windows 8 phone app with MVVM pattern for textchanged vs clickCommand sequence

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, windows-8

I am facing an issue for wizard kind of screen, user enters text in textbox and clicks on "go to Next Screen", then "go to Next Screen" related command fires prior to "text-changed" of required field and user gets annoyed message to enter data where data is already in textbox but sequence of events firing is making a problem. Can i make sure to fire "text-changed" property first and then click command?

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding UserName,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>


public RelayCommand<String> NavigateToCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _navigateToCommand
                    ?? (_navigateToCommand = new RelayCommand<String>(
                        pw =>
                        {
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.UserName))
            {
                message = "UserName is required ";
            }
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change source trigger.

```
Text="{Binding UserName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged is not available in windows store app. for reference see http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1701

Comment: It is available in Windows Phone 8 universal app. I don't know what kind of project it is, anyway he could use UpdateSourceTrigger explicit and call it in TextChanged.

Comment: i had to use custom wrapper and local:UpdateSourceHelper.UpdateSourceText="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay} as i already mentioned in comment above, I could not find textchange reflection in binding in windows store app, please suggest any link referring to windows store app with what you suggest. Thanks